# Set-ADuser not accepting Logonworkstations variable

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Goal: Use a script to add 3 workstations to all users.
Problem: Receiving error thats says variable's format is invalid. $finalworkstations.gettype() brings up null-valued expression.

Receive an error:

```
Set-ADUser : The format of the specified computer name is invalid
At \\pathwaystuff\file.ps1:37 char:9
+         Set-ADUser $logonname -LogonWorkstations $finalworkstations
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (tester:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:1210,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
```

Here's the script I have now.

```
$list = Get-ADUser -filter {LogonWorkstations -like "*"} -properties name, LogonWorkstations | select name, logonworkstations



$logonname = "someone"

Function addspecificLogon {
    param (
        $logonname
    )

        $wrklist = Import-Csv "\\pathwaystuff\anotherplace\file.csv"
        $Workstations = (Get-Aduser $logonname ` -Properties LogonWorkstations).LogonWorkstations
        $workstations += ",work1, work2, work3"

       
        #CONVERT WORKSTATION LIST TO AN ARRAY TO ALLOW FOR BETTER MANIPULATION OF DATA
        $Workarray = $Workstations.Split(",")

        #ERROR-CHECKING MEASURE: ELIMINATE DUPLICATE WORKSTATION NAMES
        $Workarray = $Workarray | Sort-Object | Get-Unique 
        
        #CONVERTING ARRAY BACK TO STRING TO SET IN AD WORKSTATIONS (NEEDS TO BE A SPECIFIC STRING FORMAT TO ADD TO AD WORKSTATION)
        $finalworkstations = ''
        foreach ($work in $Workarray) {
            $finalworkstations += ", $($work)"
        }
        Set-ADUser $logonname -LogonWorkstations $finalworkstations
        $finalworkstations
}

addspecificLogon($logonname)

Get-ADUser -identity $logonname -properties * | select logonworkstations
```

Comment: what if your target has no workstations? is this the array you want to add to AD?   `, ,  work2,  work3, work1`

Comment: @anothervictimofthemouse We don't want to include those users because if a users logon workstations are set to null or empty then they are set to all computers. Adding a workstation will set it to only the workstations added, thus limiting their logon rights.

Comment: does your filter represent that? in my testing it returned users with no value in the `LoginWorkstations` property. Try using `Get-ADUser -ldapfilter '(userWorkstations=*)` to restrict your scope to only users with values in this field.

Comment: In my testing I did come up with any users that had their logonworkstations blank. Some users had "none", "no computer" , or a variation of the sort which is still read as a value of some kind. I don't see the difference between your filter and mine considering it uses the same parameter of * to ensure that a value is inside. Though i have never used -ldapfilter before. However that isn't the part of my code that doesn't work lol...

Comment: what specific part of the code doesn't work?

Comment: 'Set-ADUser $logonname -LogonWorkstations $finalworkstations' The $finalworkstations doesn't seem to be in a format Set-ADuser likes, however this was fine until a few weeks before I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. That proved a lot simpler overall. Don't know exactly why but manipulating an array as long as possible helped.

```
  function workstations{
        $userWorkstationListLocation = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the filepath of the CSV containing the allowed workstations"
        if ($userworkstationlistlocation -eq ""){
            $userWorkstationList = "empty"
            $script:userworkstationlist = $userworkstationList 
            $script:userworkstationListLocation = $userWorkstationListLocation
        } elseif ((test-path -path $userWorkstationListLocation) -eq $false) {
            $userWorkstationListLocation = verify($userWorkstationListLocation)
        }
        $userWorkstations = Import-Csv -Path "$userWorkstationListLocation" | ForEach-Object {$_.userPC}
        
        #CSV REFERENCE LIST FOR DEFAULT LOGON RIGHTS
        $defaultWorkstationslist = Import-Csv '\\url\link\of\stations.csv'
        foreach ($station in $defaultworkstationslist) {
            $userWorkstations += "$($station.Infrastructure)"
        }    
    
        #CONFIRMING IF NEEDED TO USE CITRIX
        $CitrixUser = Read-Host "Will this user need access to Citrix? [Y/N]"
        
    #FUNCTION TO CONFIRM ADD OR SKIP CITRIX LOGON RIGHTS
    if ($CitrixUser -eq "Y"){
        foreach($station in $defaultworkstationslist){
            if ($station.Citrix -eq ""){
                continue
            } else {
                $userWorkstations += "$($station.Citrix)"
            }
        }  
    }

    #Removing Duplicates
    $userworkstations = $userWorkstations | Sort-Object | Get-Unique

    #Fixing for blanks
    $userWorkstations.where({$_ -ne "" })
  
    #converting to a list Set-AD can use
    foreach ($s in $userWorkstations){
        $s
        if ($s -eq ""){
            continue
        } else {
            $userworkstationlist += "$s,"
        }
    }

    $userworkstationlist

    $script:userworkstationListLocation = $userWorkstationListLocation
    $script:userworkstationlist = $userworkstationlist
    Write-Host "Within function $($userworkstationlist)"
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).